# Rails: How to model objects with a mix of both fixed and dynamic data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, database-design, mongoid, arbor.js

I am building a site with a database of users. I am using [arbor.js](http://arborjs.org/) to build a graph for each user.  The graph is a tree-like structure with edges and nodes that looks something like this (I had an image ready to go but apparently don't have enough reputation yet):

```
             vehicle
             /     \
            /       \
          car      truck
          /
         /
       sedan
```

and is represented by the following JSON:

```
{
   "nodes":{
      "vehicle":{
         "color":"black",
         "label":"vehicle"
      },
      "car":{
         "color":"orange",
         "label":"car"
      },
      "truck":{
         "color":"red",
         "label":"truck"
      },
      "sedan":{
         "color":"red",
         "label":"sedan"
      }
   },
   "edges":{
      "vehicle":{
         "car":{
            "weight":5,
            "directed":true,
            "color":"orange"
         },
         "truck":{
            "weight":5,
            "directed":true,
            "color":"red"
         }
      },
      "car":{
         "sedan":{
            "weight":2,
            "directed":true,
            "color":"orange"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Each graph will always have a `nodes` and `edges` object with dynamic nodes and edges. Their respective attributes (`color`, `label`, `weight` etc.) will be fixed.

I am trying to figure out how best to model this data for each user. I am using Rails with MongoDB (Mongoid), because I understand that MongoDB can save objects as documents in the database.  I'm pretty sure each user will have a graph model which I can define, but beyond that I'm not sure how to handle the nodes and edges.

I'm guessing the solution will involve `has_many`, `embeds_many`, or possibly `serialize`, but I'm unclear on how to use these with a mix of fixed and dynamic data.

Also, it would be nice to retrieve the data exactly the way it looks above so I can easily create the graph when loading it from disk.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you want exactly? Can you be more precise.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out what my model files will look like.  I'm thinking each user will embed one graph, which will embed many nodes and edges... something like that.  I'm basically looking for a way to save the object above for each user, while being able to get and set the nodes and edges of the graph.

Comment: Tell me if I am getting it right or not. You wish to have graph operations to be performed for every user with only graph data stored in his corresponding BSON record. The Graph operations you wish to have are independent of any 2 user's graph.

Comment: Yes each user will embed his own graph (ie will have a unique structure like the one above).  My real concern is how the graph is stored?  Should it be just one big  BSON object? Or should it be broken up more so it's easier to manipulate its sub-objects (if that's the right term)?

Comment: Check out my answer. I hope this is what you might be looking for. Since all you want is to perform operations within the graph of individual record, it really doesn't matter how you model it. Mongo has no issue how enriched your document is until you are to query over the collection. But in your case you are only concerned with individual record over which you are to perform operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case all you need is to perform graph operations only per user. You can follow this model.

```
{
"nodes": [{"type": "vehicle", "color":"black", "label": "vehicle"}, 
          {"type": "car", "color":"orange", "label": "car"},
          {"type":"truck", "color":"red", "label":"truck"},
          {"type": "sedan", "color":"red", "label":"sedan"}
         ],
"edges": {
    "vehicle": [
                  {"type": "car", "weight": 5, "color": "orange"}, 
                  {"type": "truck", "weight": 5, "color": "red"}
               ],
    "car": [
              {"type": "sedan", "weight": 2, "color": "orange"}
           ],
    "sedan": [],
    "truck":: []
}
```

It is like you are storing a multimap for edges. Also it is self suggestive whether its a bi-directional or not. For individual user's graph to be processed independently, it is a pretty natural model you can go with.

Tell me if it meets your requirement. Also, until you specify what kind of queries you want to perform over your collection, its not possible to suggest a model.

Also if you are starting your project you can explore some graph databases as well like [neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This definitely helps, but I was actually looking for some rails code. i.e. how is this graph data embedded for each user?  What will the User class look like?  Will there be an actual Graph model, or will it just be as simple as `field :graph` ?

Comment: From the question you asked above, it seems like all you needed was, something like `field : graph`. As per your needs, can nodes in a graph of one user be somehow related to another user's graph? If so I would recommend you to use something like neo4j (graph database). If the graph is not that big for individual user and is independent from other users, then mongo is a pretty good choice.